# SASS: Child classes according to parent class

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Is there a way we can check the parent element class & change child element class properties?

**Something like:**

```
if parentClass {
  h1{color: red;}
} else if parentClass2 {
  h1{color: blue;}
}
```

**Want CSS to be like:**

```
.parentClass h1 {
  color: red;
}
.parentClass h2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

So, if the name of the parent class changes the child class properties also changes.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use @if statement in that case but you could do something like this

```
h1 {
  color: red;

  .parent-1 & {
    color: blue;
  }

  .parent-2 & {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

The output will be

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}

.parent-1 h1 {
  color: blue;
}

.parent-2 h1 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man, i think that's the only option there. Voted! :)

Comment: Is it possible to save class name as a variable so that i can use the same name for class & CSS property value? something like .#{$color} {color: $color}